# stats::heatmap does not plot anything when the data is the same

Tags: r, heatmap

I am plotting a lot of heatmaps in a script and from time to time I have a heat map with the same value.
At the moment it does not produce anything...

```
heatmap(matrix(rep(1,25),5,5,dimnames=list(letters[1:5],letters[6:10])))
Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

[image]

***I would have expected a map with red everywhere... is there a workaround ?***

---

```
heatmap(matrix(rep(1,25)+rnorm(25),5,5,dimnames=list(letters[1:5],letters[6:10])))
```

[image]

---

Comment: What kind of workaround do you want? fail gracefully, or still give you an image? 
hint: try this `image(x)`, `image(t(x))`, `heatmap(x, scale="none")`.
Default in heatmap is to scale by row, if the matrix is symmertical. Think what happens when you scale a matrix of 1s

Comment: Thanks, you could write this as an answer...

Answer (score 1):

It works using the function `heatmap.2` from the package `gplots`

```
install.packages("gplots")    
library(gplots)

a <- matrix(rep(1,25),5,5,dimnames=list(letters[1:5],letters[6:10]))
heatmap.2(a)
```

[image]

If you don't wont the color legend on the upper left you can play around with the many options in gplots. And of course there is a "flat dendrogram" in this case.